# fsockopen equivalent in c#

Tags: php, asp.net, fsockopen

Kinda new to webrequests and such, so this is a pretty basic question imho.
*What's .NET's equivalence of PHP's fsockopen function*, especially **if I want to read and write data to the server at same time**?

Should I use:

System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url);
System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();

Something else? And how do I best read / write from it?

Answer (score 0):

WebRequest (namely HttpWebRequest ) and WebClient are only for transactional messages (i.e. request/response pairs) and not for synchronous socket communications. Is is not what you want.

For that you can either use the `System.Net.Sockets.Socket` class, or the easier-to-use `TcpClient` class. I prefer `TcpClient` because it gives you `NetworkStream` which is eaiser to work with than the BSD Socket-style API.